# Does this native pronounce wrongly the word "gorgeous"?

Tags: pronunciation

Ok, check this video at **0:17** ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kf4GonU_tlA)).

The native English man said "**you look gorgeous**"

In the dictionary

> **gorgeous**: `/ˈɡɔːrdʒəs/` ([Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gorgeous?q=gorgeous))

But in that above video, it seems the man said `/ˈɡɔːrɡəs/`.

So, Does he pronounce wrongly the word "**gorgeous**" or is there any other way to pronounce it?

Comment: The character who speaks that line is doing so in a very affected accent, and I would not take his pronunciation of anything to be conventional.

Comment: The actor **deliberately** mispronounced it to make it sound funnier or dramatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not the normal way to pronounce the word. And it is not even a standard "alternate" or even dialectal pronunciation.

I have never watched an episode of *Hannah Montana*, and I do not know anything about the character who says 'gorgeous' in this scene. Maybe he pronounces lots of words in a different (non-standard) manner, or maybe this is just a one-time (or rare) thing. If so, it is mainly for comic effect. The character definitely knows he is pronouncing the word incorrectly, so it is not an accident.

Since the first *g* in *gorgeous* is hard, by pronouncing the second *g* as hard, rather than the way it "should be" pronounced, as a *soft g*, it makes the pronunciation sound funny, and that adds to the overall humor of the scene.

Answer (score 1):

It was a very weird pronunciation. I'd surmise that the character is/was supposed to be gay and pronounced "gorgeous" in a such a manner as to emphasize that fact.